# Avoiding `NullPointerExceptions` from `toString` from `hashmap`

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to avoid a `NullPointerException` in some code that tries to compare with a string from a `HashMap`.

The `HashMap` is well defined but there may or may not be a corresponding entry in the `HashMap` so I believe this may be where my NPE and the associated Android Studio warning may be coming from.

My code is:

```
if (region_ids !=null && source_region != null && selected_id != null) {
    if (source_region.equals("it") && region_ids.containsKey("it") && !selected_id.equals(region_ids.get("it").toString())) {
        // Do stuff for mismatched region
    }
}
```

Where `region_ids` is the `HashMap`.

Am I doing enough to prevent `NullPointerException`s?

If so, why is Android Studio still giving me the warning in the IDE?

(Note that the `Android-Studio` tag is included intentionally because of the last part of this question which is AS specific.)

---

**Update**

Based on Code-Apprentice's comment and Nosyara's answer I now have the following two variations on the `if` statement but still get the NPE warning on the `toString()` method:

```
if ( region_ids_string != null && spin_region_id != null && source_region != null && selected_id != null && assoc_ids != null) {
    if ( region_ids_string.size() > spin_region_id.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
        if (source_region.equals("com_mx") && assoc_ids.get("com_mx") != null && assoc_ids.containsKey("com_mx") && !selected_id.equals(assoc_ids.get("com_mx").toString())) {
                return true;
        } else if ("com_au".equals(source_region) && assoc_ids.containsKey("com_au") && assoc_ids.get("com_au") != null && !assoc_ids.get("com_au").toString().equals(selected_id)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

So I believe I am now checking for `null`, "", and whether the `Key` exists in the `HashMap` but AS still believes it is possible for the statements to generate an NPE...

Comment: I don't know where the NPE is coming from, but the basic steps to figure it out are the same. Break your IF statement into pieces and start printing stuff out. You'll probably find something is odd. And are you sure this is where your NPE is coming from?

Comment: The problem I have is that I cannot reproduce the error myself. I only see it reported in the Google Play Developer console (but the obfuscation/deobfuscation loses the detail currently!). That and the fact that I see the warning in the IDE. So picking it apart `if` clause by `if` clause is a problem in itself at the moment. If also like to know if I'm using `containsKey()` properly in this context.

Comment: "Am I doing enough to prevent NullPointerExceptions?" - no. Without seeing all your code, it is possible that `region_ids.get("it")` yields null making `region_ids.get("it").toString()` throw an NPE, if the implementation of Map that you're using allows for null values.

Comment: I thought the `region_ids.containsKey("it") would ensure that `region_ids.get("it")` would not be `null'. Is that not the case? If not, what is the best way to check that? I tried `region_ids.get("it") != null` in the `if` instead of the `containsKey` test but still got the warning in the IDE.

Comment: "Before the above I also check..." Please show the code that goes with this verbal explanation.

Comment: @FatMonk Note that if you do `region_ids.put("it", null);` then `region_ids.containsKey("it")` returns `true` but `region_ids.get("it")` will be `null`. so your assumption is not correct.

Comment: @FatMonk "I tried region_ids.get("it") != null` in the if instead of the containsKey test but still got the warning in the IDE." You need both checks because they test for different things.

Comment: Is `region_ids.put("it","")` equivalent to `region_ids.put("it",null)? I'm probably getting confused here but I thought that a NullPointerException meant that the pointer didn't point to anything rather than it pointed to _something_ with a value of null. So an object can have a value of null but if the object doesn't exist then any pointer to it would be pointing to nothing is null....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reverse condition with constant to the left, you'll automatically check it for NULLs. Like so:

```java
if ("it".equals(source_region) && 
region_ids.containsKey("it") && 
!(region_ids.get("it").toString().equals(selected_id))) {
    // Do stuff for mismatched region
}
```

Comment: Oooh, that's an interesting suggestion. Is that always the case - can you explain a bit more how that works because they could be really useful.

Comment: I've now tried this and Android Studio is still giving me the warning on the toString() method. Surely there must be a way of checking to make using this method safe.